# Connection refused when running stream_socket_server & client through apache

Tags: php, apache, sockets, centos

I have a CentOS 5.9 box running Apache 2.2.3 and PHP 5.4.8.

I'm trying to set up a server using PHP so that a C Application on another server can easily query some information from our webserver.

I also want to be able to send packets to the server locally - from the same webserver - to conveniently control the server.

The problem is that, when both the server as well as the client are accessed through the browser / apache, the client never manages to connect. When I execute either the client or the server through the CLI, it suddenly works.

I tested the same code on a Ubuntu box where it works without any issues.

For testing/debugging, the server automatically shuts down after 30 seconds.

To clarify:

---

- Browser goes to serverstart.php
- Browser goes to client.php
- Result: client.php keeps loading until serverstart.php hits the 30 second shutdown, then responds with Connection refused

---

- Browser goes to serverstart2.php, which uses exec, passthru or system('php -f serverstart.php');
- Browser goes to client.php
- Result: Does not work. Client hangs until serverstart.php shuts down after 30 seconds.

---

- CLI: php -f serverstart.php
- Browser goes to client.php
- Result: Works

---

- Browser goes to serverstart.php
- CLI: php -f client.php
- Result: Works

---

- Browser goes to serverstart.php
- CLI: echo "Test" | nc localhost 8000
- Result: Works

---

client.php

```
<?php

$client = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:8000", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($client === false) {
    echo "Failed to connect: $errorMessage";
}

fwrite($client, "This is a test" . PHP_EOL);
echo stream_get_contents($client);
fclose($client);
```

serverstart.php

```
<?PHP
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($server === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
}

$start = microtime(true);

while((microtime(true) - $start) < 30) { // 30 second timeout
    $client = @stream_socket_accept($server, 1);

    if ($client) {
        echo 'Client Found';
        $message = fgets($client, 1024);
        echo 'Client said:' . $message;
        fwrite($client, 'The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($client);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea whats going on here and how I can get it to work to call both through the browser?

Edit: I wanted to add that no firewall is running on the box. iptables comes up blank and SELinux is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Rather delayed answer but without knowing your apache and php configurations, or the differences between your Ubuntu and CentOS configurations. I believe permissions may be the source of your issue.

For example, when you run the script via CLI and you use `su apache; php serverstart.php;` you should get the same results as when run from the browser. As opposed to running the CLI as root. This is due to apache not having permission to connect with the specified ip/port.

Additionally ensure your port 8000 is not being used by Apache (or other service) as it is a common port in a lot of configurations and may be blocked when trying to access it via php. Generally somewhere in your Apache configuration it will contain Listen *:8000 or similar.

EG: `http://localhost:8000 -> Apache -> php -> fsockopen('tcp://localhost:8000')` (already in use), php times out, port is opened, then client.php responds with Connection Refused.

You can check the conflict by creating a script (test.php) that contains only `<?php sleep(120);` browse to `http://localhost/test.php`, then execute your servertstart.php from the CLI while the test.php is sleeping.

Also within your serverstart.php be sure to execute `fclose($server);` or `stream_socket_shutdown($server, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);` at the end of your script to ensure that the server is not left in an unusable state. Also add at least a `usleep(500)` to the end of your while to prevent extra cpu usage. You should also exit the loop if `stream_socket_accept` returns false since it indicates an error occurred rather than calling `@stream_socket_accept` from within the loop.

```
while($timer < 30 && ($client = stream_socket_accept($server, 1))){
  $timer = (microtime(true) - $start);
  //code here
}
```

If the above doesn't help what I believe is occurring is by default your Apache web server acts as a wrapper for PHP and is executed using apache's user and group permissions. This is why your web files generally have user-group apache permissions with 750 on directories and 640 on files.
This allows apache to access, and denies anonymous access, to the directories and files within your virtual host directory, then when it reads a PHP file, apache executes php and outputs the result as text/html.
However Apache does not have access to other system resources

You can check the running user by executing `echo exec('whoami');` from within one your scripts and navigating to it from your browser.

There are several workarounds for the permission issue, the majority of which are bad practice, and would present security vulnerabilities on the server.

You may be able to resolve the issue by executing `umask(0);` from within serverstart.php and client.php prior to connecting. This means that anything created will use 0777 permissions, including sockets. Or you can try setting `chmod(755)` on serverstart.php and client.php to see if allowing anonymous users execute rights on the files resolves the issue.

Otherwise you can look into creating a wrapper for your web service such as `suexec` or `php-fpm` and run it with fastcgi through Apache executing as user-name/user-group and the proper umask settings. Then ensure your user has permissions to open a connection on the ip/port specified.