# PHP - Socket communication between servers

Tags: php, apache, sockets

After years of searching for answers in other people's posts, I finally have to ask. 
I'm currently trying to implement a WatchDog / Shepherd pattern to monitor long processes (from 2-3 minutes to several hours)  running in my app. 
The app is fairly complicated, and I started working on it mid-project, so I don't grasp it entirely. 
Two servers are running : The one we'll call FACADE, with an Apache/2.4.10 (Debian), and CALCULUS, with an Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux).
I have designed things like this :

The Shepherd initializes on FACADE, when the user click on a button that triggers a long process

The process, running on CALCULUS, initialises a WatchDog that connects to the Shepherd using a TCP Socket.

At some key points of the process, the WatchDog 'barks', i.e sends a string to the Shepherd to tell him at which step the Process is (the string is like "M(essage)#S(tarting)#Indexing", "M#C(ompleted)#Indexing", "M#S#Transfert", "M#C#Transfert"...) and if there's been an error (in which case it sends "E#Indexing" => Error happened during Indexing)

When he gets a Message from the dog, the Shepherd does what he has to (process, displaying to the user, filling a bit the progress bar...)

That my friends, was purely theory. Now comes the Implementation :

```
/**
 *Implements the Singleton Design Pattern
 *And of course, the Watchdog Pattern, using a Socket to communicate with the Shepherd.
 */
class Watchdog{

    /** Singleton Design pattern. Use $watchdog = Watchdog::getInstance() to use the doggy */
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct(){
            $this->init();
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
            if (Watchdog::$instance === null)
                    Watchdog::$instance = new Watchdog();

            return Watchdog::$instance;
    }

    private $socket;
    private $connected = false;

    private function init(){
            $this->socket = fsockopen("tcp://A.B.C.D", 4242, $errno, $errstr);
            if($this->socket === false){
                    echo "$errno : $errstr";
            }else{
                    $this->connected = true;
            }
    }

    public function kill(){
            fclose($this->socket);
            Watchdog::$instance = null;
    }



    public function bark($message){
            if($this->connected === true){
            fwrite($this->socket, "M#".$message."\n");
            }
    }

    public function alert($err){
            if($this->connected === true){
                    fwrite($this->socket, "E#".$err."\n");
            }
    }

}

?>
```

And the Shepeherd :

```
/**Implements the Singleton Design Pattern,
 * And the Shepherd / Watchdog Patter, using a Socket to communicate with the Watchdog.
 */
class Shepherd{

    /** Singleton Design pattern. Use $shepherd = Shepherd::GetInstance() to use the shepherd */
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
            $this->init();
    }
    public static function GetInstance(){
            if (self::$instance === null)
                    self::$instance = new Shepherd();

            return self::$instance;
    }

/**Instance variables **/
    private $socket;
    public $initialised = false;
    public $doggyConnected = false;
    private $dogsocket;

/**Init : Initializes the shephrd by binding it to the watchdog on the 4242 port**/
    private function init(){

            ob_implicit_flush();
            $this->socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242", $errno, $errstr);
            $this->initialised = true;
    }

/**Sit And Wait : Waits for Dog connection**/
    public function sitandwait(){
            //Waiting for doggy connection
            do {
                    if (($this->dogsocket = stream_socket_accept($this->socket)) === false) {
                            echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($this->dogsocket)) . "\n";
                            break;
                    }else{
                            $this->doggyConnected = true;
                    }
            }while($this->doggyConnected === false);
    }

/**Listen to Dog : Waits for Dog to send a message and echoes it **/
    public function listentodog(){
            if($this->dogsocket !== false) {
                            $buf = fgets($this->dogsocket);
                            return $buf;
            }
    }

/**Kill : Kills the shepherd and closes connections **/

    private function kill(){
            stream_socket_shutdown($this->socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
            stream_socket_shutdown($this->dogsocket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
            fclose ($this->dogsocket);
            fclose ($this->socket);
            Shepherd::$instance = null;
    } 

   /**Run : Runs the Shepherd till he got a message from dog **/
    public  function run(){
   if($this->doggyConnected === false)
                    $this->sitandwait();
            return $this->listentodog();
    }


}
```

After trying those without success on the real website, I decided to try and see what was happening on both servers, thanks to netcat command. 
 There's the catch : When I fake the Shepherd thanks to netcat, the dog can connect and send accurate data about the process. When I fake the dog thanks to netcat --send-only, the Shepherd gets the data and does the right things with them. 
But when I run both from the application, I get a "Connexion refused" at the dog->init() (fsockopen : Connexion refusée), and of course, the Shepherd dies from Timeout.
**But wait there's more !!** You might think that the problem comes from the connection, and with netcat It doesn't come up because I don't do the connection from PHP (or I don't connect to a PHP opened socket).

 I thought that too; I wrote two scripts, test_dog.php and test_shepherd.php, that are used EXACTLY in the same way than in my real live application. When I try to make them communicate, It works ! It even works with a real dog(monitoring a real application process) and test_shepherd.php, or with a real Shepherd (from my app), and test_watchdog.php

I decided to come here to ask you guys from help, because I'm utterly lost. i don't understand why It doesn't work with the real code, but does with the test_ scripts. In those, I made sure to use the objects exactly the same way than in the real application.

To show you everything, here are my test_ scripts :
test_watchdog.php

```
require "Watchdog.php";

$dog = Watchdog::getInstance();
$dog->bark("Try try try");
$dog->bark("Trying hard !!");
sleep(5);
$dog->bark("Trying harder to see...");
sleep(2);
$dog->bark("END");
$dog->kill();
```

test_shepherd.php

```
require "Shepherd.php";

$shep = new _Shepherd();
echo $shep->run();
```

... i think that's All. Please answer if you have the faintest idea that might help me, you're my last hope, I'm lost and desperate...
Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT** : On CALCULUS, the Watchdog is called by a Thousand-lines-long class, called Process (that runs the main process). The point is to be able to call Watchdog nearly everywhere in the code, where the user might have to wait. 
Here is for instance the __construct of Process, intializing the Watchdog, and one of the methods that calls the $doggy->bark();

```
 public function __construct($photoId = 0) {
        $this->params = array();
        $this->doggy = Watchdog::GetInstance();

        $this->params['photoid'] = $photoId ;

        date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Paris');
}

public function transfertProject() {
    try {
    $this->doggy->bark('s#transfert');
    //Traitement long
    set_time_limit (0);
    ini_set('post_max_size', 0);
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 0);
    $response = false;

    if (!isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
        $upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        return "Le fichier ne semble pas avoir été posté,  vérifier la taille maximal d'upload";
    }
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filename = "../Workspace/projects/".$name;
    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
        $response = $this->unzipProjectArchive();
        unlink($filename);
    }
    $this->doggy->bark('c#transfert');
    return $response;
  } // END TRY
   catch (Exception $ex)  {
   //Watchdog telling shepherd
   $this->doggy->alert('transfert');
}
}
```

Comment: Just a blind shoot: Have you check the rights. From web you are always `www-data` and from command line is another user and not `www-data`!? But, whatever read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735561/connection-refused-when-running-stream-socket-server-client-through-apache#24742563

Comment: It the problem comes from the rights, shouldn't it crash when I'm running the Dog from the server to a netcat command, or the dog from the netcat and the Shepherd from the server ? 
Thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: Was just a blind shoot because i know a little about sockets, but im not into netcat and dog , so i can not help more, sry

Comment: Is it possible to have the portion of code of watchdog in action on CALCULUS side ?

Comment: Here you are, kind sir :)

Comment: Did you tried your tests classes one by one with netcat, or together ? :-)

Comment: Actually I see two issues in your tests codes, but I don't know if this is your problem or just a typing error ! The first is the new _Shepherd() (the underscore), second is new _Shepherd can't work because your constructor is private, so you have to use Shepherd::getInstance().